# DpInst fails to install filter driver: Could not get services associated with driver package

Tags: windows, driver, dpinst

When installing a filter driver through an .INF file with DpInst, it reports the following error:

> ERROR:  Could not get services associated with driver package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The INF sections should be named `[DefaultInstall.NT]` and `[DefaultInstall.NT.Services]`.